# Passing reference on every method call or once on instance creation

Tags: java

I'm making a simple game, and it has a single instance of a class named `Game` that deals with all the logic of the game.

Many of the classes in the project have a method called `tick()` which is called from within the `Game` instance 60 times per second and deals with updating information. Such instances are stored in list(s) in the `Game` class.

This method requires access to the `Game` class and currently looks like this:

```
MyClass {
    public void tick(Game game) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is - would it be *better* to do as I am doing now and pass a reference hundreds and thousands of times per second to all the instances that require it or simply pass a single reference to these instances on creation and have the classes look like so:

```
MyClass {
    private Game game;
    public MyClass(Game game) { this.game = game }
    public void tick() { ... }
}
```

Basically, how taxing it is to pass this reference so many times every second?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Perhaps another option is to mark all the required members of the `Game` class as static and calling them as such without a reference at all?..

Comment: Don't do the static thing. You would be making all the static variables essentially globals.

Comment: @DJClayworth but if there is only one instance of `Game`, would that really be such a bad thing?

Comment: 1) Globals are a problem because you have no control over where they are accessed from. 2) You are restricting yourself to NEVER EVER create another game. What happens if you want do some kind of analysis by saying "what would happen if the game were in this state"? What about if you wanted to write a server that could play multiple games against many opponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably have to profile this to get a definitive answer. You're balancing the cost of pushing an argument onto the stack and accessing the argument inside the function versus accessing an instance field from within the function. My guess is that this will be close to a wash.

If `game` changes identity during execution, then there's a big win for passing it as an argument every time. It doesn't sound like that applies in your case, however.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that taxing.  You should make the decision based on design, not speed.

Does the Game passed in ever change?  If not, it's probably best to pass it in during the constructor, and make the field final for clarity.

But, are there many many Games?  If so, it probably makes sense to pass it in the method so you don't have to construct tons and tons of MyClass - you can make due (perhaps) with only one.

Comment: There is only a single instance of `Game` at any point in time.

Comment: Even if there were many games, as long as each instance waiting for the tick is associated with only one then you can pass it at construction time.

Answer (score 2):

Please profile before you find this to be a bottleneck. I don't think this really matters in your program.

But the cons are that the memory occupied by MyClass will increase if it has **Game** as a member. If you are creating a lot of **MyClass** your program will use more memory.

Answer (score 1):

I was sure that there is no (or minimal) taxing but decided to verify this fact. Here is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0;  i < 10000000;  i++) {
            t.foo();
        }
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("no args: " + (after - before));


        before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0;  i < 10000000;  i++) {
            t.foo(t);
        }
        after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("with args: " + (after - before));

    }

    private int foo() {
        return hashCode() * 2;
    }

    private int foo(Object arg) {
        return arg.hashCode() * 2;
    }
}
```

I ran it several times and did not see any significant difference between `foo()` and `foo(Object)` calls performance. Moreover sometimes arg-full version runs faster than arg-less:

```
c:\temp>java -cp . Test
no args: 17
with args: 20

c:\temp>java -cp . Test
no args: 17
with args: 18

c:\temp>java -cp . Test
no args: 16
with args: 19

c:\temp>java -cp . Test
no args: 17
with args: 18
```

Comment: That is interesting. Can such tests really be considered unequivocal?

Comment: This is not quite an accurate test. The first version of `foo` is calling `this.hashCode()`. To be closer to OP's case, class Test should have a member object and call `obj.hashCode()`. That will then include the expense of a field lookup. When I ran that test, the no-arg version of `foo` was about 50% slower.